# Particles projecting ahead of object to which they are attached. Help!

Tags: particles, error

`

> enter code here[image]

`I am following this tutorial: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OcxrBrDQ7Lc

The particles when I render are projecting far ahead of the animated jet they are parented to flying across the sky. Why would particles be ahead of the animated path? Followed the settings from the tutorial very closely and only deviated slightly.
[image: You can see particles ahead of the jet on the photo.1]

Comment: Hello and welcome. It's hard to tell from this crop only. Also, the tutorial is 40 min long. Can you share a file with the jet (emitter object) and the particles? (https://blend-exchange.com/)

Comment: When you say file, do mean another screenshot?

Comment: I mean the blend file so we can have a look.

Comment: I’m afraid it won’t let me/idk how. I’m sending from my phone so I can’t upload from my computer as a guest. I dropped the file onto my phone but can’t figure out how to upload it. In the meantime here is an actual png file. Apologies for making this even more difficult but I’m a total noob.